# Re-platforming existing website to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm about to re-platform existing website to WordPress. It is a big site with e-commerce (this section is on Magento). To get the working files of existing website, I used HTTrack as I did not have an access to FTP. This means that the files are static even thought already existing website has custom built CMS.

Do you think it is the right thing to use files I got off HTTrack and convert them into WordPress? I'm thinking about developing the WordPress website locally as I do not have an access to FTP details yet and then once it's developed, move it to the actual server. Do you also think that I will have to use 301 redirect to connect URLs with old website? I will have the same URL structure on new WordPress website as it is on old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [migration/integration options](http://www.wpsolver.com/magento-plugins-for-wordpress-migration-integration/) for Megento and WordPress.  It seems, by your question, you may be more interested in a migration to Woocommerce using a plugin like [FG Magento to WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-magento-to-woocommerce/).

It offers the following free features, as well as premium features.

- migrates the product categories
- migrates the product categories images
- migrates the products
- migrates the product thumbnails
- migrates the product images galleries
- migrates the product stocks
- migrates the CMS

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! 
So there is no way that I could add Magento into WordPress and display all data from Magento on WordPress website. I have to migrate all data from Magento into WooCommerce and display it that way. Is that correct?

Comment: I was assuming, by your question, that you were more interested in a migration opposed to an integration.  Here is some [information](https://www.cminds.com/best-ways-to-integrate-wordpress-and-magento/) for an Integration.  Please be sure to accept the answer if it has been helpful.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert existing website that uses custom build CMS into WordPress and also add already existing Magento (one part of the website) into new built WordPress website. The website will have the same layout and information, however it is going to use WordPress CMS.
Does it make any sense? Do you have any suggestions how to handle this type of problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to customize theme manually. If you migrate to Woocommerce there are pre-made themes that may have most of the customization you require already completed.  I found a decent walk through of the [complete migration process](https://www.fredericgilles.net/how-to-migrate-from-magento-to-woocommerce/).  Please be sure to accept the answer if it has been helpful

Comment: So you would suggest to create customised WordPress website first with all content and then add Magento content to it, is that correct? 
When I migrate Magento information to Woocommerce, will I still be able to use Magento to update products etc. or will I have to use Woocommerce for that and Magento will not be function anymore?

Comment: I think things are getting muddied.  Do you want to completely move off of the Magento platform and onto WordPress (migration) or do you want to manage the store aspect of the WordPress  website within Magento (integration)?  In a migration, Magento would be completely eliminated.  Which ever you choose would be dependent upon what your end goals are.  I am sure there are pros and cons to both migration and integration, but either way there will be a customized WordPress website involved.

Comment: I'm sorry about that! I still want to use Magento platform for shop part of the website. But all information from Magento will be displayed in WordPress website as well as rest of the site which will be done by WordPress. It is only shop part of the website that is stored in Magento. 
Does this make any more sense?

Comment: I would build your custom WordPress website and use this plugin, [Magento WordPress Integration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/).  This plugin is currently being maintained and has a semi-active support page with Plugin Author involvement.  In the notes at the bottom for the plugin it states "This plugin does not allow you to completely avoid using Magento on your website, it simply helps you to get your WordPress and Magento themes seamlessly integrated."   Check out their [demo page](http://demo.mwi-plugin.com/).  Please accept the answer if it has been helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I appreciate it a lot! I will try it and see if it works.